# How to properly chain RxJS observables together with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a projectService to retrieve projects. Each project in turn has methods to retrieve corresponding tags and modules.

What i try to do is populate an instance property projects: Project[] with all corresponding tags and modules and when everything is populated call another method, which depends on the data.

I know my approach is not working because my map operation returns the projects before the observables in the for loop complete, but I have no idea how to do it properly.

```
class ProjectService {
  getAll(): Observable<Project[]> {...}
}
```

```
class Project {
  tagCollection: Tag[];
  moduleCollection: Module[];

  getTags(): Observable<Tag[]> {...}
  getModules(): Observable<Module[]> {...}
}
```

```
this.projectService
  .getAll()
  .pipe(
    map(projects => {
      for (const project of projects) {
        project.getTags().subscribe(tags => {
          project.tagCollection = tags;
        });
        project.getModules().subscribe(modules => {
          project.modules = modules;
        });
      }
      return projects;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(projects => {
    this.projects = projects;
    this.someOtherMethod();
  });
```

## Update

I have tried both solutions and edited them to retain the project type and use a similar coding style. Both solutions work and seem to do the same thing in my project context. But I'm unsure which solution is better and if the edits i made are breaking any reactive best practices. Can someone elaborate on this?

### Solution 1 from Reqven

```
this.projectService
  .getAll()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(projects =>
      combineLatest(
        projects.map(project =>
          combineLatest([project.getTags(), project.getModules()]).pipe(
            map(([tags, modules]) => {
              project.tagCollection = tags;
              project.modules = modules;
              return project;
            })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(projects => {
    console.log(projects);
    this.projects = projects;
    this.someOtherMethod();
  });
```

### Solution 2 from NateDev

```
this.projectService
  .getAll()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(projects => from(projects)),
    mergeMap(project => 
      combineLatest([project.getTags(), project.getModules()]).pipe(
        map(([tags, modules]) => {
          project.tagCollection = tags;
          project.modules = modules;
          return project;
        })
      )
    ),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe(projects => {
    console.log(projects);
    this.projects = projects;
    this.someOtherMethod();
  });
```

Comment: Don't subscribe in the rxjs operators or place a subscription inside of another subscription. Please create a minimal reproduction of your project in stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a many different ways to perform batch calls asynchronously.

So what I like to do is flatten my data as I believe it's easier to perform
operations on a more flat structure. After I'm done performing operations on the objects I regroup/reassemble them using the [toArray](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray) operator

If you have any question regarding the operators I used feel free to ask. I highly recommend you to play around with the different [rxjs transformation operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation).

Be aware my code below is definitely not the **best** solution, but it works fine!

Hope it works for you! 
**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynu5ay?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, from, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'
import { delay, map, mergeMap,switchMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;

  data: Partial<Project>[] =  [
    { name: 'foo'},
    { name: 'foo'}
  ]

  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.getProjects().pipe(
      mergeMap(projects => from(projects)),
      mergeMap((project) => {
        const tag$ = this.getTagsByProjectName(project.name);
        const module$ = this.getModuleByProjectName(project.name);
        return combineLatest([tag$,module$]).pipe(map(([tag,module]) => ({...project, tag, module})))
      }),
      toArray()
    ).subscribe({
      next: projects => {
        console.log(projects);
        this.name = JSON.stringify(projects);
      }
    })
  }

  getProjects() : Observable<Partial<Project>[]> {
    return of(this.data).pipe(
      delay(100)
    )
  }

  getTagsByProjectName(name: string){
    const tag = 'bar';
    return of(tag).pipe(delay(100));
  }

  getModuleByProjectName(name: string){
    const module = 'baz';
    return of(module).pipe(delay(100));
  }
}

interface Project {
  name: string; 
  tag: string; 
  module: string;
}
```

Comment: Did the solution above help?

Comment: I didn't have time to evaluate the answers in my project yet. Will do that ASAP and give feedback.

Comment: I have edited my question. It now contains an edited version of your solution that seems to work in my project but I'm still uncertain about some details.

Comment: You can also rewrite my solution using a switchMap if you only want to allow one active inner subscription at a time. Both solutions are correct in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like that work for you ?
Might need some tweaking to fit your project, but it seems to be working.

```
this.projectService.getAll()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(projects => !projects.length
      ? of([])
      : combineLatest(
          projects.map(project => combineLatest([
            project.getTags(),
            project.getModules()
          ]).pipe(
            map(([tags, modules]) => ({tags, modules})),
            map(data => ({
              ...project,
              tagCollection: data.tags,
              moduleCollection: data.modules
            })),
        ))
    ))
  ).subscribe(projects => {
    this.projects = projects;
    this.someOtherMethod();
  });
```